# autofac wiring Type to my logger

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, serilog

I have a logger as follows:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{ 
    private ILogger _logger;

    public Logger(Type type)
    { 
        _logger =  LogManager.CreateLogger(type);
    }
     .... removed
```

I am trying to build a log module:

```
public class LogModule : Autofac.Module
{       
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        const string propertyNameKey = "Autofac.AutowiringPropertyInjector.InstanceType";


        builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

I have to find and inject the type into the `Logger`, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847068/how-can-i-resolve-the-correct-logger-type-using-autofac) question is asking, but [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847068/how-can-i-resolve-the-correct-logger-type-using-autofac) does property injection, i need ctor injection.

How can I get contextual logging, ie log per Type?

Comment: don't know about autofac, but are you looking for something like this? var StudentLogger = Log.Logger.ForContext<Student>();

Comment: https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration ?

Comment: Did you [read the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Preparing`of the registration object. This code is taken from the [autofac page](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html).

```
public class LoggingModule : Autofac.Module
{

    private static void InjectLoggerProperties(object instance)
    {
        var instanceType = instance.GetType();

        // Get all the injectable properties to set.
        // If you wanted to ensure the properties were only UNSET properties,
        // here's where you'd do it.
        var properties = instanceType
          .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
          .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ILog) && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);

        // Set the properties located.
        foreach (var propToSet in properties)
        {
            propToSet.SetValue(instance, LogManager.GetLogger(instanceType), null);
        }
    }

    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
          new[]
          {
             new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog),
                (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType)
             ),
          });
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        // Handle constructor parameters.
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;

        // Handle properties.
        registration.Activated += (sender, e) => InjectLoggerProperties(e.Instance);
    }
}
```

This code:

```
private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
      new[]
      {
         new ResolvedParameter(
            (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog),
            (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType)
         ),
      });
}
```

injects a new logger (using the class name) to the CTOR.

```
class ClassA 
{
    ... 
    ClassA(ILog logger) => this.logger = logger; // logger was created by Autofac via LogManager.GetLogger("ClassA")
}
```

Hope that is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Do you know what this does? this inject properties. not ctor.

Comment: Copy paste. I have seen this already. in fact it is a link in my question.

Comment: @DarthVader:  `OnComponentPreparing` injects an instance of ILog (based on the class type) in the CTOR. In your question you are writing " i need ctor injection. ".

Comment: @DarthVader: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/797c5cff0c3688e3a64c695805d1ab699f756db5/src/Autofac/Builder/IRegistrationBuilder.cs, Line 226-227 -> "Add a handler for the Preparing event. This event allows manipulating of the parameters that will be provided to the component."