# Inject ILogger<T> into constructor that only expects ILogger

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, serilog

This is similar to [How to inject named logger generic ILogger<T> as ILogger into constructor using IServiceCollection and NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65725313/9300801)

However I am looking for a solution using Serilog + Autofac.

Hopefully there is a solution that works for both ASP.net Core 6 and console .NET 6

Typically  MEL ILogger is used like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger) 
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogInformation("Constructor");
  }
}
```

It is tedious to manually type
`ILogger<MyClass>` everywhere like `ILogger<MyOtherClass>`, `ILogger<YetAnotherClass>`

Is there a way to omit the `<MyClass>` part, but actually receive `ILogger<MyClass>` like below? (Apparently in [How to inject named logger generic ILogger<T> as ILogger into constructor using IServiceCollection and NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65725313/9300801) the questioner claims to have a solution using Autofac, but I do not have enough Reputation to ask him in the comment)

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

//public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
  public MyClass(ILogger logger) // <<<<< notice that ILogger is used, instead of ILogger<T>
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogInformation("Constructor");
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"Is there a way to omit the <MyClass> part, but actually receive ILogger<MyClass> like below?"_ - not using the stock `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` in .NET, no.

Comment: @Dai how about if we do not use the stock ```Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection``` ?

Comment: It looks like several proposed AutoFac / NLog solutions are given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847068/how-can-i-resolve-the-correct-logger-type-using-autofac maybe you can adapt them to Serilog

Answer (score 1):

I think my nuget package is exactly what you are looking for:

Here you can read about how to use it:
https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Serilog.Autofac

You can download it from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Serilog.Autofac

I also have a nuget package for Microsoft Logging + Autofac for the same purpose (i.e. omit the generic type parameter):
https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac